# Start / Stop keypress event jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress

I have a problem. I want to stop keypress event when space is pressed, then I want to do something and finally I need to "restart" this function. It is possibile? How can I do this?

Thank you in advance

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
     if(e.keyCode == 32)
          // stop keypress function
          // do something
          // restart keypress function
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have two choices.

Disable the handler:

```
$(document).on('keypress', function keypressHandler(e) {
    //disable handler
    $(document).off('keypress');

    //do stuff

    //enable keypress handler
    $(document).on('keypress', keypressHandler);    
});
```

Use a flag:

```
var keyHandlerActive = true;
$(document).on('keypress', function(e) {
    if (!keyHandlerActive) { return; }
    keyHandlerActive = false;

    //do stuff

    keyHandlerActive = true;    
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I use the first method and it work very well.

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these functions:

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

OR

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Full code:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 32) {
    e.preventDefault(); // e.stopPropagation();
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can play with it like this as I have added two buttons for both situations and by default the SPACE will be disabled. Check it out please:

**HTML**

```
<input id="myinput" type="text">
<input id="space_flag" type="hidden" value="0">
<br/>
<input id="enable_space" type="button" value="Enable Space">
<br/>
<input id="disable_space" type="button" value="Disable Space">
```

**JQuery**

```
$(function(){
    $("#myinput").keypress(function(event){        
        if(event.keyCode == 32 && $("#space_flag").val()==0){
            return false;        
        }
    });

    $("#enable_space").click(function(event){
        $("#space_flag").val(1);
    });

    $("#disable_space").click(function(event){
        $("#space_flag").val(0);
    });
});
```

Working example http://jsfiddle.net/1pn4cLak/

Answer (score 0):

Your turn off condition is space, but turning back on condition is not mentioned.. so I am using a timer below.. change it as you like

To try the demo,

1. Type any key except space to see it get logged
2. Press space to turn off for 10 seconds (or change code to make it until a process complete)
3. function turns On after 10 seconds

The function simply turns off (**logical off as bind/rebind might become a pain if overused**) for 10 seconds when space is pressed.

```js
var logicalOff = false;
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
     if (logicalOff) { return true; } //well we just ignore and return until turned On
     $('div').text(e.which);
     if(e.which == 32) {
       logicalOff = true; // stop keypress function
       setTimeout(function () { // restart keypress function
         logicalOff = false;
         $('div').text("turned on now");
       }, 10000);          
       $('div').text("turned off for 10 seconds");
     }     
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```